# website seemingly logs users in without sending the password to the server; how does this work?

Tags: javascript, security

On the stellar website FAQ (https://www.stellar.org/faq/#_Why_does_my_client_log_me_out_on_refresh_) it says the following

> Your password never gets sent to our server: instead, it’s used in your current browser 
>   window to decrypt your secret key. That way we never have access to your stellars. We chose
>   not to store this password locally, so that it doesn’t get written to your local disk (we 
>   may add the ability to cache the password locally, depending on user demand).

How exactly does (or could) this work? The usual workflow would be to send the password to the server, which then hashes it and compares it to the hash stored in a user database. I can't see a way of this working (safely) by only doing it client side...

Comment: My guess: encrypted data is sent to your browser and decrypted locally. You don't send credentials to the server; the server sends data to anyone who asks for it, but the data can only used by someone with correct requires credentials (via cryptography).

Comment: If I understood that correctly, does that not make my login details vulnerable to brute-force attacks? (attacker tries to log in as me, with wrong password, gets encrypted stuff from server which it can then brute force)

Comment: Yes, if my guess is correct, then your data is indeed vulnerable to offline brute force attacks. Pick a *very* strong password.

Comment: @apsillers Only the key is vulnerable, not the password itself (which is their claim) as the password itself is never passed to the server.

Comment: @Mark I haven't looked at it closely; I was assuming that, since password-based decryption of the key happens without server intervention, an attacker could perform unlimited password guesses without anyone knowing. (This presupposes the attacker can identify when a correct guess has been made without server intervention as well, which might not be true. If the only thing being decrypted is a randomly-generated key, and human-sensible output only comes when that key is used on the server, then the server could slow or block that client's brute force attempts.)

Comment: @apsillers And I think you're correct in your assumptions. I was merely pointing out that the password itself isn't vulnerable, which is what the OP's quote states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a shot, the workflow goes something like this during registration:

- I enter my password and submit the form.
- This sends a request to the server to get a KEY.
- The  KEY comes back and is encrypted on the client with the password.
- The Encrypted KEY is sent to the server.
- The Encrypted KEY is stored in the database.

During Login:

- I enter my credentials and submit the form.
- This sends a requested to the server to get my KEY.
- The KEY comes back and is decrypted on the client with the password.
- Presumably at this point some sort of 'authorized' message or signal is somehow sent back to the server, or possibly even the unencrypted key?

You ask about this being secure, and well it's not. The are specifically saying this (in their FAQ) regarding why they can't help you retrieve your password, and it does protect your password but it does NOT protect your account.

Anyone that has access to a packet sniffer can get the encrypted key, and depending on the level of encryption possibly break it open. Faking that encryption data going back to the server to verify a login is, I am sure, a joke, given that all of the encryption and decryption code has been passed to the client to be executed during registration or login.

But that's how it's conceivable, at least.

The browser is always in the hands of the enemy!